# Error related to load table in R

Tags: r

I recently updated R to 3.5.1. It was working fine for couple of days but then I started getting error for any code that I run (including following simple examples)

e.g.

```
> A = 2

Error in .Call("rs_hasExternalPointer", obj, TRUE) : 
 C symbol name "rs_hasExternalPointer" not in load table

> A = "a"
Error in .Call("rs_hasExternalPointer", obj, TRUE) : 
 C symbol name "rs_hasExternalPointer" not in load table
```

Here's the sessionInfo and version information

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.1.19

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          5.1
>   year           2018
>   month          07
>   day            02
>   svn rev        74947
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
>   nickname       Feather Spray

I tried to search online but could not find much information on the error. I have a feeling that some path or packages is missing. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried working in base R and I did not get any error message. So, I reinstalled RStudio and everything seems to be working fine. So, I guess there was some issue with RStudio but I don't know what. Thanks!